# Unable to install PHPUnit and Pear Packages on My Windows System using Xampp

Tags: php, phpunit

When am installing the phpunit below error being displayed

```
'D:\XAMPP\htdocs\Selenium_Test>pear install phpunit.de/PHPUnit 
Attempting to discover channel "phpunit.de"...
Attempting fallback to https instead of http on channel "phpunit.de"...
unknown channel "phpunit.de" in "phpunit.de/PHPUnit"
invalid package name/package file "phpunit.de/PHPUnit"
install failed'
```

And also for Channel is:

```
'D:\XAMPP\php>pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
Discovering channel pear.phpunit.de over http:// failed with message: channel-ad
d: Cannot open "http://pear.phpunit.de/channel.xml" (File http://pear.phpunit.de
:80/channel.xml not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 410 Gone))
Trying to discover channel pear.phpunit.de over https:// instead
Discovery of channel "pear.phpunit.de" failed (channel-add: Cannot open "https://pear.phpunit.de/channel.xml" (Connection to `pear.phpunit.de:443' failed: 
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.))'
```

As soon as possible please help me with this problem.

Comment: End of Life for PEAR Installation Method: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method

Answer (score 0):

The PEAR installation Method is abbandoned (as described [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method) ).

Follow the instruction for install on windows [here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html).

A simply way is:

1. Download the phpunit.phar [here](https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar) and save in the current directory folder.
2. Make a script files for lauch it: `echo @php "%~dp0phpunit.phar" %* > phpunit.cmd`
3. launch it, as example `phpunit --version`

Hope this help